# How to send an alert or message back to the application being used to update the database if the entry could not be inserted to database

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have three database tables:

```
Student{RollNo(primary key), Name etc.}


Book{Id(primary key),NoOfCopiesAvailable etc.}

IssuedBook{RollNo(Foreign Key referencing Student(RollNo)), Id(Foreign Key referencing Book(Id)}
```

Now, a student can't be issued more than 5 books(means a RollNo can't be in the IssuedBook table more than 5 times. Right?) and a book can only be issued if 'NoOfCopiesAvailable'>0.

So, I wrote the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_IssuedBook ON IssuedBook
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS BEGIN
IF((SELECT NoOfCopiesAvailable FROM Book WHERE Id=(SELECT Id FROM INSERTED))>0 AND (SELECT COUNT(RollNo) FROM StudentBook)<5)
INSERT INTO StudentBook SELECT RollNo,Id FROM INSERTED
ELSE
//Stucked up here. Want to send a message/alert back to application(C#). Don't know how to achieve that.
END
```

Can this be achieved? If yes, Please let me know and if possible provide the coding. Or if there is any other way doing out this whole thing, then please do share. I would be very thankful for your help.
Thank You!
NOTE: Using Windows form coded in C# to update the database, SQL Server 2008

Comment: There are many ways to do this.  I suggest you do some [research](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021(v=vs.71).aspx) on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Putting business logic inside a trigger isn't a good idea, and having the trigger communicate back a specific error message to the C# code is difficult. Also your trigger isn't using a transaction so it's possible a student could end up with more than 5 books.

I would put both the SELECT COUNT and INSERT statement inside a transaction. This could be in C#, or in a stored procedure. This guarantees that another SQL query can't INSERT a record until the transaction either succeeds or gets rolled back.

Here's some C# code with Linq to get you started.

```
public static bool CheckoutBook(int bookID, int studentID)
{
    try
    {
        using (var dc = new LibraryDataContext())
        {
            using(var tran = dc.Connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var bookCount = dc.StudentBook.Count(a => a.StudentID == studentID);

                if (bookCount < 5)
                {
                    var studentBook = new StudentBook();
                    studentBook.StudentID = studentID;
                    studentBook.BookID = bookID;
                    studentBook.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                    dc.StudentBook.InsertOnSubmit(studentBook);

                    dc.SubmitChanges();
                    dc.Transaction.Commit();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //the transaction failed for some reason
    }

    return false;
}
```